# JSF Internal Variable Persistence

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, managed-bean

In JSF and Java EE, I have an `ArrayList`, I fill this `ArrayList` with an object I create based on user input. The user just has a simple form which allows them to fill some values, click a button so it gets added to a table.

It being added to a table is with the purpose of having a for loop that iterates through all the values the user adds.

The problem is that once a value is added the page reloads to add the value. But when it reloads the internal value of the `ArrayList` is lost, so the next time they add something there's still only one (The Latest) value.

Here's some generic code illustrating the usability:

```
public class Car {
    private String model;
    private String brand;
    private String year;

    // Getters and setters
}

@ManagedBean(name = "Car")
public class CarMaker {
    ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();

    // There are values we pass directly from browser
    private String localModel;
    private String localBrand;
    private String localYear;

    // Getters and setters

    public void generateCars() {
        // Generate XML external elements
        for (int i = 0; i < carList.length; i++) {
            // Generate XML internal elements
        }
        // Finish up XML
    }

    public Car carFill() {
        Car tempCar = new Car();
        tempCar.setModel(getLocalModel());
        tempCar.setBrand(getLocalBrand());
        tempCar.setYear(getLocalYear());

        return tempCar;
    }

    public void addToTable() {
        carList.add(carFill());
    }
}
```

And here's the button, and the table:

```
<p:commandButton value="＋" id="Add" actionListener="#{Car.addToTable()}" 
            ajax="false" update="growl" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

<!-- Table start -->
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{Car.carList}">
    <p:column headerText="Model">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<!-- Table end  -->
```

The code itself does work. It gets added, everything else works. However, I need to know how to add "persistence" to the `ArrayList` variable, so that even after the mini-refresh that happens due to pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> button, the old information added by the user is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `@ViewScoped` annotation to your `CarMaker` managed bean.

You probably will have to implement [`java.io.Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) in both your `Car` and `CarMaker` classes as well.

[This article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes) by the legendary [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) explains the use of the different scopes supported in JSF2.

Comment: I had a crushing suspicion it'd be a really simple solution like this. I'll test and give correct answer if it is. Could you please expand your answer to explain why `@ViewScoped` is the right approach to the solution, etc... Mostly for people who find this through Google.

Comment: I have confirmed this works (View Scoped)

Thanks for the edit with added information. I'll mark this as the correct answer. 

Good night